# How to monitor total data written to drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, software-rec, monitoring, data-transfer

Is there a tool for windows that totals up how much data has been written to the hard drive. I've tried resource monitor and it's not what I'm looking for.

Something along the lines of this in mac, where it shows the total data written and read:

Anything like this for windows 7??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this small application: http://www.hddled.com/download/

At least it's page says that it shows total amount of read and written data.

Comment: looks interesting, I've read a few things about a virus with that software.

Comment: @zm15: mandatory disclaimer: I am NOT affiliated with that software in any way. However, I couldn't find any reports about viruses on it, and my virus scanner (up-to-date Symantec) couldn't find one either. (But still there can be one, can't be sure)